# app('cart') not giving proper data from the session in the constructor and in service provider file after Laravel update from 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

we are not getting data from app('cart') before upgrading its working properly.
we are using cartalyst package for cart and we store whole cart object in session but when we try to get in cart service provider it's giving us blank object but in Laravel debugger it's showing it was there and also in other pages like product page and home page it's working properly but in cart page its not working after update from Laravel 5.3 from 5.2

```
<?php

namespace App\Cart\Providers;

use App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('App\Cart\Interfaces\CartServiceInterface', function () {
            return new \App\Cart\Services\CartService(app('cart'));
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because of session variable we can not access in a constructor and in service provider because I declare session middleware in middleware group which loads after so I removed from that and add in middleware option in kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```